# Complex mapping in dapper without subqueries

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

If I have an object like

```
class Thing
{
 public string A { get; set; }
 public string B { get; set; }
 public string C { get; set; }
 public string D { get; set; }
}
```

Dapper works really well with:

```
return conn.QuerySingle<Thing>(
    @"SELECT A, B, C, D
      FROM [Thing] WHERE Id = @id", new { id });
```

But what if my class structure is

```
class Thing
{
 public string A { get; set; }
 public string B { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<Stuff> { get; set; }
}

class Stuff
{
 public string C { get; set; }
 public string D { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get Dapper to map to that structure, assuming the Enumerable will always contain 1 item in the Enumerable so in reality I am just representing the same data in a different way.

The Dapper tutorials I've seen are quite complex and contain subqueries, but ideally my query shouldn't change because it already returns all the data that should map to the new structure.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://dapper-tutorial.net/result-multi-mapping#example---query-multi-mapping-one-to-many

Comment: I don't have an inner join. That links falls under "more complex than what I'm trying to do".

Comment: You just need a join and a `splitOn` option. Search for dapper + splitOn

Comment: Join with what? My SQL query is linear "SELECT A B C D", that's all

Comment: @Nick: then i don't understand your model. If an `IEnumerable<T>` is in a class that represents a table, this property is used for the mapping between this main table and it's related table. So one `Thing` could have 0-n `Stuff`. Maybe you neeed another class that is decoupled from the database and a factory method/constructor from `DbThing` to `Thing`.

Comment: The class used to be like the first example and everything worked fine but it is now changed and I don't think it matters why.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own Custom Type Mapper. I've written an article and some samples here:

https://medium.com/dapper-net/custom-type-handling-4b447b97c620